# GrailsUI (YUI) data table hover event

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, yui-datatable

How to make the data table rows change color as hover over it. The YUI example is here [link text](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_rowselect.html)

I tried something like

```
    <script>
  GRAILSUI.myDataTable.subscribe("rowMouseoverEvent", GRAILSUI.myDataTable.onEventHighlightRow);
  GRAILSUI.myDataTable.subscribe("rowMouseoutEvent", GRAILSUI.myDataTable.onEventUnhighlightRow);
  GRAILSUI.myDataTable.subscribe("rowClickEvent", GRAILSUI.myDataTable.onEventSelectRow);
</script>
```

thanks,

Comment: really good, Grails UI with YUI (+1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.. got it working.. for anyone interested, you need to wrap the above statements in

YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function () {  });

so that the table is initialized.